# TD reordering with jquery-ui sortable, chrome not rendering again

Tags: jquery-ui, dom, google-chrome, rendering, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery ui sortable to sort TD's in a TR. In chrome this seems to be indenting the TDs to the right. From a similar question found on SO, I reckon this is because of chrome adding an extra TD which is not even visible under console, and is only being rendered.

How do make this work?

I have found this snippet that tries to force chrome to render again, but this does not seem to work.

```
var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
$('TD:eq(0)').parent().get(0).appendChild(n);
n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
```

The similar question found on SO says that he was able to solve the issue by calling a function .render() on his view item, I presume this is a custom function for a library the asker was using.

Any ideas on how to force refresh the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

To those who are facing a similar issue, I found that hiding the parent element and showing it after a small delay(10ms works), keeps things working.